# Is there a way to new a class that's the same type as another class without directly specifying it

Tags: c#-4.0

I have extension method that does something like this

```
public static void DoStuff(this ObjectContext context)
{
    using(var newContext = new MyEntitiesContext())
    {
        // do stuff
        newContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I was wondering if there a way to new a context of the same type as the context passed in instead of specifying MyEntitiesContext?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont know if newing up a DB context in an extension method is the right way to go. Maybe you should rethink your solution here. Just a thought. Also, what is the difference between ObjectContext and MyEntitiesContext? If this is L2SQL, and you look at the code for "MyEntitiesContext" - it will inherit from ObjectContext - so there's no need to pass in ObjectContext, just pass in MyEntitiesContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind reflection:

```
var context = Activator.CreateInstance(context.GetType());
```

Now you either need a base Type or - if you still don't mind reflection - you can simply call the method by name. Or, since you are using C#4 you could go with dynamic.

Edit: You could also Go this way:

```
public static void DoStuff<T>(this T context) where T : ObjectContext, new()
{
    using(var newContext = new T())
    {
         // do stuff
        newContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```